# Bison reduce errors. Why is it using that error placement instead of this one?

Tags: yacc, bison

I am extremely confused. I have an error in my file and `funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS` is NOT used.

Why? This is what is bothering me. funcBodyLoop2 has an empty rule so it can never fail. And to fail funcBodyLoop2 must reduce at least once before it can attempt to run the rule `| funcBodyLoop2 funcBody` By looking at these rules the only place it can get an error is funcBody. So i added `| funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS` (aEOS checks of one or more end of statements, which are newlines and ';'). So since funcBodyLoop2 is already reduce should the error always be at `| funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS`? Running it i always got reduce to a rule further back then i wanted. I end up writing `| error aEOS` just to see what happens and i see funcBodyLoop2 b being reported after my error.

My question is, why is it using that rule or not using `funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS`. I dont understand.

```
funcBodyLoop2:
    | funcBodyLoop2 funcBody
    | funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS  { doerror("funcBodyLoop2", YYRECOVERING()); yyclearin; yyerrok; }
    | error aEOS  { doerror("funcBodyLoop2 b", YYRECOVERING()); yyclearin; yyerrok; }


funcBody:
      funcBodyA
    | funcBodyS  mEOS
    | funcBodyEs aEOS
    | error aEOS  { doerror("funcBody", YYRECOVERING()); yyclearin; yyerrok; }
```

Comment: There's not enough grammar show here to see what is going on, and your question is not at all clear, but `error` is completely unlike a normal terminal in what it does, so its probably that you're confused as to what it does.  Post a more complete grammar, the exact input that is not doing what you expect, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: Ok i could do that in a few hours. But maybe just simply explaining how the error terminal is different from others would help. I can say simply now i expect an error in `funcBodyLoop2 funcBody` to be caught and handled in `| funcBodyLoop2 error aEOS` and to keep looping inside of funcBodyLoop2 but that isnt the case

Comment: error rules are ignored until a state is reached when current lookahead can neither shift or reduce.  At that point, it pops states off the stack looking for one with an error rule.  When it finds one, it shifts the error token, and then discards input tokens until it finds one that is acceptable to the new current state.  At that point it attempts to continue.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your grammar has a shift/reduce conflict between the two error rules in funcBodyLoop2 and a reduce/reduce conflict between the first funcBodyLoop2 error rule and the funcBody error rule.  The latter means that the funcBody error rule can never fire, as the funcBody2 rule will always take precedence (its earlier in the file).

So if you get an error at the very beginning of a funcBody2 (you're trying to parse one and the very first token is something that can't legally begin a funcBody2 or follow an empty funcBody2 in the current contex), it will trigger the second funcBody2 error (shift) and then throw away tokens until it sees an `aEOS` (since that's the only legal thing that fits there), which it will then shift and reduce that `b` error rule.

If you get an error after reducing at least one funcBody2 (so not in the very first token), then it ends up triggering the first funcBody2 error rule (non-`b`).

Comment: I'm still very confused. I even reread the chapter on it in flex&bison. Ok so just for (my) sanity reasons i added error to one of my rules and saw the rules no longer work because it expects an error. Ok good thats what i was expecting. In flex&bison i saw this example `stmt_list: error ';' | stmt_list error ';'` so if there is an error in a rule, it will be reduced as that rule (maybe i am getting my terms wrong. i mean this error will get reduced as a valid stmt_list and loop)

Comment: `take precedence (its earlier in the file).`. Ealier in the file? or because it was evaluated first in the stack? that cant make sense because then all rules with just use the first error seen in globalLoop: (now you really know i am confused). I didnt use all the rules at the same time. Although i did allow it to have conflicts just to see what would happen. My input is `var ="string"blah; cout << "string"`. cout works fine if blah isnt there (which causes the error). What i did was take EVERY error rule out of my file.

Comment: Now when i now get an error the app plainly stops and doesnt evaluate anymore. funcBody in my example above is written like this now (and funcBodyLoop2 doesnt have any error rules). So my question is when the code enters `funcBodyLoop2: . |` `funcBodyLoop2: | funcBodyLoop2 . funcBody` `funcBody: . funcBodyEs aEOS` and gets an error in funcBodyEs, why isnt it using `funcBody: error aEOS` instead? It just stops as if there were no error rules at all. I can tell it isnt evaluating because i put Message macros which shows up in my console.

Comment: I tried making a dummy test example but i failed. Must have copied or did something wrong, it keeps saying 'a' gives me a syntax error. I think it has to do with my backend code. http://www.pastie.org/1559127 <-- since i couldnt get the basic syntax i couldnt try error handling. In this code case i would write `| testLoop test aEOS` at line 31 and i am sure line 7 will fail and cause msg 4 & 5 not to be printed. Which is what i dont understand.